# How to make background of OpenGL window transparent?

Tags: c, opengl-es, background, window, transparent

I am making an opengles 2.0 application where i need to make the background of the window transparent and then show a blended object over it. Please can someone tell me how can i make window background transparent. The appearance i want is that it sud appear as if only a blended object is in front.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

With regards,

Aditya

Comment: Which platform are you on?  Android?  iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Since the CE API is a subset of the Win32 API, the following answer might set you on the right track:

[How to make an OpenGL rendering context with transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052940/win32-how-to-make-an-opengl-rendering-context-with-transparent-background/4201472#4201472)