# How to make an OpenGL rendering context with transparent background?

Tags: c, winapi, opengl, transparency

Rendering contexts usually have a solid color on the background (black or whatever, see the image below):

[image]

I'm wondering if it's possible to setup a window, with no decorations AND with the transparent background, while allowing me to render OpenGL stuff on it.

This would give the illusion that the triangle is floating on the screen. The transparent background should allow you to see the desktop or other applications that might be behind it.

Could you please exemplify with source code?

Platform: Windows (win32 only)

Comment: great set of demos with source taking you through step by step: http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/index.html

Comment: The "OpenGL Layered Windows" demo is basically the best way to do it, a pbuffer is much faster than rendering into a DIB directly.DIB is usually using the software renderer where pbuffer is accelerated

Answer (score 112, accepted):

After spending some reputation on a unsuccessful bounty to get *some help* on this issue, I finally realized how complex was the problem I was interested in.

The few individuals that have accomplished this task [don't share much](https://web.archive.org/web/20120615071641/http://coreytabaka.com/programming/cube-demo/). During my research I found different ways to achieve what I was looking for. One of the most interesting ones is **AeroGL**, and it shows [snippets of code](http://www.jose.it-berater.org/smfforum/index.php?topic=2844.0) using a technique that was not mentioned so far, which is rendering the graphics to a [device-independent bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183494(VS.85).aspx) (DIB).

To close this thread permanently, the **source code below** implements that technique. The code itself is a slight modification of an application presented [here](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/opengl/layeredopengl.xml) (big thanks to *Andrei Sapronov Y.*).

The end result can be seen in the image below:

[image]

The code has been tested on Windows XP (32-bits) and Windows 8.1 (32-bits).
**Enjoy!**

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")

#include <assert.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#ifdef  assert
#define verify(expr) if(!expr) assert(0)
#else verify(expr) expr
#endif

const TCHAR szAppName[]=_T("TransparentGL");
const TCHAR wcWndName[]=_T("WS_EX_LAYERED OpenGL");

HDC hDC;            
HGLRC m_hrc;        
int w(240);
int h(240); 

HDC pdcDIB;                 
HBITMAP hbmpDIB;            
void *bmp_cnt(NULL);        
int cxDIB(0); 
int cyDIB(0);   
BITMAPINFOHEADER BIH;       


BOOL initSC()
{
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);        
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);        
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);          
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);            

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);             
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}

void resizeSC(int width,int height)
{
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
}

BOOL renderSC()
{   
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                              // Drawing Using Triangles
        glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                      // Set The Color To Red
        glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top
        glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);                      // Set The Color To Green
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
        glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);                      // Set The Color To Blue
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    return 0;
}

// DIB -> hDC
void draw(HDC pdcDest)
{
    assert(pdcDIB);

    verify(BitBlt(pdcDest, 0, 0, w, h, pdcDIB, 0, 0, SRCCOPY));
}

void CreateDIB(int cx, int cy)
{
    assert(cx > 0); 
    assert(cy > 0);

    cxDIB = cx ;
    cyDIB = cy ;

    int iSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);   
    memset(&BIH, 0, iSize);

    BIH.biSize = iSize;
    BIH.biWidth = cx;   
    BIH.biHeight = cy;  
    BIH.biPlanes = 1;   
    BIH.biBitCount = 24;    
    BIH.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    if(pdcDIB) 
        verify(DeleteDC(pdcDIB));

    pdcDIB = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    assert(pdcDIB);

    if(hbmpDIB) 
        verify(DeleteObject(hbmpDIB));

    hbmpDIB = CreateDIBSection(
        pdcDIB,         
        (BITMAPINFO*)&BIH,  
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,     
        &bmp_cnt,       
        NULL,
        0);

    assert(hbmpDIB);
    assert(bmp_cnt);

    if(hbmpDIB)
        SelectObject(pdcDIB, hbmpDIB);
}

BOOL CreateHGLRC()
{
    DWORD dwFlags = PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP;

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd ;
    memset(&pfd,0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR)) ;
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR); 
    pfd.nVersion = 1;                       
    pfd.dwFlags =  dwFlags ;                
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA ;        
    pfd.cColorBits = 24 ;                   
    pfd.cDepthBits = 32 ;                   
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE ;       

   int PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(pdcDIB, &pfd);
   if (PixelFormat == 0){
      assert(0);
      return FALSE ;
   }

   BOOL bResult = SetPixelFormat(pdcDIB, PixelFormat, &pfd);
   if (bResult==FALSE){
      assert(0);
      return FALSE ;
   }

   m_hrc = wglCreateContext(pdcDIB);
   if (!m_hrc){
      assert(0);
      return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch(msg) 
    {
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            return 0;
        break;

        case WM_CREATE:
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            if(m_hrc)
            {
                wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
                wglDeleteContext(m_hrc) ;
            }
            PostQuitMessage(0) ;
        break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            renderSC(); // OpenGL -> DIB
            draw(hDC);  // DIB -> hDC
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

        case WM_SIZE:
            w = LOWORD(lParam); h = HIWORD(lParam);         
            wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
            wglDeleteContext(m_hrc);

            CreateDIB(w, h);
            CreateHGLRC();
            verify(wglMakeCurrent(pdcDIB, m_hrc));

            initSC();
            resizeSC(w, h);
            renderSC();
        break;

        default: 
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR str,int nWinMode)
{   
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WindowFunc;
    wc.cbClsExtra  = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra  = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hThisInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW);
    wc.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("RegisterClassEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, szAppName, wcWndName,
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 200, 150, w, h,
                    NULL, NULL, hThisInst, NULL);
    if(!hWnd){
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("CreateWindowEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    verify(SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0x0, 0, LWA_COLORKEY));

    MSG msg;
    while(1) 
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_NOREMOVE)){
            if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
            else return 0;
        }
    } 

    return (FALSE); 
}
```

Comment: It's worth saying that this technique is not practical for complex rendering and graphics animations. Copying GPU data to the RAM for each frame is very demanding on the CPU, resulting in low FPS. Check the comments on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780756/glflush-takes-very-long-time-on-window-with-transparent-background/4780874#4780874

Comment: Note that in Windows Vista and Windows 7 you can achieve quite the same effect as in my x11argb demo below. The PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR supports a new flag to enable composition. I've yet to create a demo for this, though. Not going to happen until April, though, when I've got time for that again.

Comment: I had these pragma comments `#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")
` in 2020 64bit.

Comment: Hi, how about other systems like ubuntu? how can I test your code there? I didn't understand which part of your code makes Window transparent. (I am new to OpenGL)

Comment: @Parisa.H.R This code depends on certain Windows APIs and therefore its exclusive to Windows. It won't make a Gnome/KDE/XFCE/etc window transparent but one can always use the search box on the top of this page to search how to make transparent windows on other desktop environments.

Comment: @karlphillip, so what should I do if I want your example in Ubuntu? I see [this answer from you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909283/9484913) but it is for Ubuntu 10.04 and I can't compile it.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I can't answer that but here are a few tips. Pick a desktop environment for Linux. Then, research how to make a transparent window on that desktop environment. Install the required libraries on your system. You will certainly find posts online that use or mention older versions of those C/C++ libraries.  So remember to adjust the paths to those libraries when invoking the compiler to build the application. You are free to create a new post on stackverflow and ask new questions. The comment section here will not provide all the answers you need to get this done. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much @karlphillip you help me so much. I found it.

Answer (score 45):

Since all the answers given so far target Windows only, but there's surely also a demand doing this on X11 with a composited window manager, for reference I post my example code here (also to be found at https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl/x11argb_opengl.c

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * A demonstration of OpenGL in a  ARGB window 
 *    => support for composited window transparency
 *
 * (c) 2011 by Wolfgang 'datenwolf' Draxinger
 *     See me at comp.graphics.api.opengl and StackOverflow.com
  
 * License agreement: This source code is provided "as is". You
 * can use this source code however you want for your own personal
 * use. If you give this source code to anybody else then you must
 * leave this message in it.
 *
 * This program is based on the simplest possible 
 * Linux OpenGL program by FTB (see info below)
 
  The simplest possible Linux OpenGL program? Maybe...

  (c) 2002 by FTB. See me in comp.graphics.api.opengl

  --
  <\___/>
  / O O \
  \_____/  FTB.

------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <GL/glxext.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xrender.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

#define USE_CHOOSE_FBCONFIG

static void fatalError(const char *why)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", why);
    exit(0x666);
}

static int Xscreen;
static Atom del_atom;
static Colormap cmap;
static Display *Xdisplay;
static XVisualInfo *visual;
static XRenderPictFormat *pict_format;
static GLXFBConfig *fbconfigs, fbconfig;
static int numfbconfigs;
static GLXContext render_context;
static Window Xroot, window_handle;
static GLXWindow glX_window_handle;
static int width, height;

static int VisData[] = {
GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, True,
GLX_RED_SIZE, 8,
GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
GLX_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
None
};

static int isExtensionSupported(const char *extList, const char *extension)
{
 
  const char *start;
  const char *where, *terminator;
 
  /* Extension names should not have spaces. */
  where = strchr(extension, ' ');
  if ( where || *extension == '\0' )
    return 0;
 
  /* It takes a bit of care to be fool-proof about parsing the
     OpenGL extensions string. Don't be fooled by sub-strings,
     etc. */
  for ( start = extList; ; ) {
    where = strstr( start, extension );
 
    if ( !where )
      break;
 
    terminator = where + strlen( extension );
 
    if ( where == start || *(where - 1) == ' ' )
      if ( *terminator == ' ' || *terminator == '\0' )
        return 1;
 
    start = terminator;
  }
  return 0;
}

static Bool WaitForMapNotify(Display *d, XEvent *e, char *arg)
{    
    return d && e && arg && (e->type == MapNotify) && (e->xmap.window == *(Window*)arg);
}

static void describe_fbconfig(GLXFBConfig fbconfig)
{
    int doublebuffer;
    int red_bits, green_bits, blue_bits, alpha_bits, depth_bits;

    glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, &doublebuffer);
    glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_RED_SIZE, &red_bits);
    glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_GREEN_SIZE, &green_bits);
    glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_BLUE_SIZE, &blue_bits);
    glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_ALPHA_SIZE, &alpha_bits);
    glXGetFBConfigAttrib(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, &depth_bits);

    fprintf(stderr, "FBConfig selected:\n"
        "Doublebuffer: %s\n"
        "Red Bits: %d, Green Bits: %d, Blue Bits: %d, Alpha Bits: %d, Depth Bits: %d\n",
        doublebuffer == True ? "Yes" : "No", 
        red_bits, green_bits, blue_bits, alpha_bits, depth_bits);
}

static void createTheWindow()
{
    XEvent event;
    int x,y, attr_mask;
    XSizeHints hints;
    XWMHints *startup_state;
    XTextProperty textprop;
    XSetWindowAttributes attr = {0,};
    static char *title = "FTB's little OpenGL example - ARGB extension by WXD";

    Xdisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!Xdisplay) {
        fatalError("Couldn't connect to X server\n");
    }
    Xscreen = DefaultScreen(Xdisplay);
    Xroot = RootWindow(Xdisplay, Xscreen);

    fbconfigs = glXChooseFBConfig(Xdisplay, Xscreen, VisData, &numfbconfigs);
    fbconfig = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<numfbconfigs; i++) {
        visual = (XVisualInfo*) glXGetVisualFromFBConfig(Xdisplay, fbconfigs[i]);
        if(!visual)
            continue;

        pict_format = XRenderFindVisualFormat(Xdisplay, visual->visual);
        if(!pict_format)
            continue;

        fbconfig = fbconfigs[i];
        if(pict_format->direct.alphaMask > 0) {
            break;
        }
        XFree(visual); visual = NULL;
    }

    if( !visual || !fbconfig ) {
        fatalError("No matching FB config found");
    }

    describe_fbconfig(fbconfig);

    /* Create a colormap - only needed on some X clients, eg. IRIX */
    cmap = XCreateColormap(Xdisplay, Xroot, visual->visual, AllocNone);

    attr.colormap = cmap;
    attr.background_pixmap = None;
    attr.border_pixmap = None;
    attr.border_pixel = 0;
    attr.event_mask =
        StructureNotifyMask |
        EnterWindowMask |
        LeaveWindowMask |
        ExposureMask |
        ButtonPressMask |
        ButtonReleaseMask |
        OwnerGrabButtonMask |
        KeyPressMask |
        KeyReleaseMask;

    attr_mask = 
        CWBackPixmap|
        CWColormap|
        CWBorderPixel|
        CWEventMask;

    width = DisplayWidth(Xdisplay, DefaultScreen(Xdisplay))/2;
    height = DisplayHeight(Xdisplay, DefaultScreen(Xdisplay))/2;
    x=width/2, y=height/2;

    window_handle = XCreateWindow(  Xdisplay,
                    Xroot,
                    x, y, width, height,
                    0,
                    visual->depth,
                    InputOutput,
                    visual->visual,
                    attr_mask, &attr);

    if( !window_handle ) {
        fatalError("Couldn't create the window\n");
    }

#if USE_GLX_CREATE_WINDOW
    int glXattr[] = { None };
    glX_window_handle = glXCreateWindow(Xdisplay, fbconfig, window_handle, glXattr);
    if( !glX_window_handle ) {
        fatalError("Couldn't create the GLX window\n");
    }
#else
    glX_window_handle = window_handle;
#endif

    textprop.value = (unsigned char*)title;
    textprop.encoding = XA_STRING;
    textprop.format = 8;
    textprop.nitems = strlen(title);

    hints.x = x;
    hints.y = y;
    hints.width = width;
    hints.height = height;
    hints.flags = USPosition|USSize;

    startup_state = XAllocWMHints();
    startup_state->initial_state = NormalState;
    startup_state->flags = StateHint;

    XSetWMProperties(Xdisplay, window_handle,&textprop, &textprop,
            NULL, 0,
            &hints,
            startup_state,
            NULL);

    XFree(startup_state);

    XMapWindow(Xdisplay, window_handle);
    XIfEvent(Xdisplay, &event, WaitForMapNotify, (char*)&window_handle);

    if ((del_atom = XInternAtom(Xdisplay, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0)) != None) {
        XSetWMProtocols(Xdisplay, window_handle, &del_atom, 1);
    }
}

static int ctxErrorHandler( Display *dpy, XErrorEvent *ev )
{
    fputs("Error at context creation", stderr);
    return 0;
}

static void createTheRenderContext()
{
    int dummy;
    if (!glXQueryExtension(Xdisplay, &dummy, &dummy)) {
        fatalError("OpenGL not supported by X server\n");
    }

#if USE_GLX_CREATE_CONTEXT_ATTRIB
    #define GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2091
    #define GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2092
    render_context = NULL;
    if( isExtensionSupported( glXQueryExtensionsString(Xdisplay, DefaultScreen(Xdisplay)), "GLX_ARB_create_context" ) ) {
        typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);
        glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB" );
        if( glXCreateContextAttribsARB ) {
            int context_attribs[] =
            {
                GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
                GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 0,
                //GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB        , GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
                None
            };

            int (*oldHandler)(Display*, XErrorEvent*) = XSetErrorHandler(&ctxErrorHandler);
            
            render_context = glXCreateContextAttribsARB( Xdisplay, fbconfig, 0, True, context_attribs );

            XSync( Xdisplay, False );
            XSetErrorHandler( oldHandler );

            fputs("glXCreateContextAttribsARB failed", stderr);
        } else {
            fputs("glXCreateContextAttribsARB could not be retrieved", stderr);
        }
    } else {
            fputs("glXCreateContextAttribsARB not supported", stderr);
    }

    if(!render_context)
    {
#else
    {
#endif
        render_context = glXCreateNewContext(Xdisplay, fbconfig, GLX_RGBA_TYPE, 0, True);
        if (!render_context) {
            fatalError("Failed to create a GL context\n");
        }
    }

    if (!glXMakeContextCurrent(Xdisplay, glX_window_handle, glX_window_handle, render_context)) {
        fatalError("glXMakeCurrent failed for window\n");
    }
}

static int updateTheMessageQueue()
{
    XEvent event;
    XConfigureEvent *xc;

    while (XPending(Xdisplay))
    {
        XNextEvent(Xdisplay, &event);
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case ClientMessage:
            if (event.xclient.data.l[0] == del_atom)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        break;

        case ConfigureNotify:
            xc = &(event.xconfigure);
            width = xc->width;
            height = xc->height;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/*  6----7
   /|   /|
  3----2 |
  | 5--|-4
  |/   |/
  0----1

*/

GLfloat cube_vertices[][8] =  {
    /*  X     Y     Z   Nx   Ny   Nz    S    T */
    {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 0
    { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 1
    { 1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 2
    {-1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 3

    { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 4
    {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 5
    {-1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 6
    { 1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 7

    {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 5
    {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 0
    {-1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 3
    {-1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 6
    
    { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 1
    { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 4
    { 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 7
    { 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 2
    
    {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 5
    { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 4
    { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 1
    {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 0

    {-1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 3
    { 1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 2
    { 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 7
    {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 6
};

static void draw_cube(void)
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][3]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][6]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
}

float const light0_dir[]={0,1,0,0};
float const light0_color[]={78./255., 80./255., 184./255.,1};

float const light1_dir[]={-1,1,1,0};
float const light1_color[]={255./255., 220./255., 97./255.,1};

float const light2_dir[]={0,-1,0,0};
float const light2_color[]={31./255., 75./255., 16./255.,1};

static void redrawTheWindow()
{
    float const aspect = (float)width / (float)height;

    static float a=0;
    static float b=0;
    static float c=0;

    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Clear with alpha = 0.0, i.e. full transparency
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-aspect, aspect, -1, 1, 2.5, 10);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light0_dir);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light0_color);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light1_dir);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, light1_color);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_POSITION, light2_dir);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_DIFFUSE, light2_color);

    glTranslatef(0., 0., -5.);

    glRotatef(a, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(b, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(c, 0, 0, 1);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

    glColor4f(1., 1., 1., 0.5);

    glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    draw_cube();
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    draw_cube();

    a = fmod(a+0.1, 360.);
    b = fmod(b+0.5, 360.);
    c = fmod(c+0.25, 360.);

    glXSwapBuffers(Xdisplay, glX_window_handle);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    createTheWindow();
    createTheRenderContext();

    while (updateTheMessageQueue()) {
        redrawTheWindow();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The main trick is getting the right FBConfig. You need to ask for a alpha channel **and** test the associated `XRenderPictFormat` for the presence of an alpha mask.

Comment: Uowwww! Incredible! I compiled it with: `g++ gl_transparent.cpp -o gl_transparent -lGL -lX11 -lXext -lXrender`. This could become a community wiki, if we are still doing that sort of thing these days.

Comment: @karlphillip: In my github repository you'd have found a makefile. And a variant of this demos that uses a fragment shader to add a wave effect – just for eyecandy. Unfortunately it's not possible to incorporate the "background" into the shader effect, because the whole background is only created by the compositor after all the windows have drawn their contents.

Comment: @datenwolf I originally was asking for assistance but I succeeded in converting your code to modern OpenGL. I will post my solution here in a bit for future reference.

Comment: HeHe! Great job ,Thanks!I was already afraid we would be left only with win32 solution :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tutorials. I also want it without border. I want to make a rubberband(drawing rectangle on screen) using opengl but I found no example of it.

Comment: @syk435 is your implementation available?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you don't need XRenderPictFormat from the Xrender extention. When you loop through your fbconfigs, to find a candidate, just make sure that `visual->depth` is `32` instead of just `24`. Also, don't forget to `XFree(visual)` inside the loop to avoid a memory leak (`glXGetVisualFromFBConfig` allocates a new XVisualInfo instance each time)

Comment: @mchiasson: You definitely must use XRenderPictFormat, since the value that matters is the alphamask, which you can get only through that interface. There are plenty of depth=32 visuals with a zero alpha mask, thus don't work for this. *To emphasize this: When I did the work on getting an alpha masked pixel format reliably, the key to get it work was using XRenderPictFormat; without that it only works if the first depth=32 visual encounterd has an appropriate alphamask*. Yeah, freeing that visual might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you @datenwolf

Answer (score 32):

I know this is possible with Windows 7, not sure about earlier versions.

To get rid of the window border you need to remove the `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` style from the window and add the `WS_POPUP` style:

```
DWORD style = ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
style |= WS_POPUP;
::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

To make the background of the OpenGL window transparent, you will need to use the `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` function:

```
DWM_BLURBEHIND bb = {0};
bb.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE;
bb.fEnable = true;
bb.hRgnBlur = NULL;
DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd, &bb);
```

You will also need to specify 0 for the alpha value when calling `glClearColor`.

```
glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
```

Also, when creating your OpenGL context, make sure you allocate an alpha channel.

Now your background should be fully transparent. If you keep the window decorations, then the background will use the Aero blur look and you can adjust the level of transparency using the alpha value in `glClearColor`.

Comment: Thank you, but DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow() is a part of DWM, which doesn't belong to the Win32 API. This solution works for Windows Vista and above.

Comment: @karlphilip: Pre-Vista Windows:es don't have desktop compositing, so I'm not sure you can do it nicely there.

Comment: @karlphilip. Sorry, I haven't personally gotten transparent OpenGL windows working with XP, but I remember seeing posts on the OpenGL forum about it. Trying looking through the following search results for more information: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site:www.opengl.org+transparent+window

Comment: This was really helpful, but I want to add the following: For me the above method rendered all of the background with the default Win7 blur and fake light reflections. To get rid of the blur and get a completeley transparent window, I set the `bb.hRgnBlur` parameter to `CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 1, 1);` and `bb.dwFlags` to `DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;`. This will blur exactly one pixel and show the rest of the window (where cleared with glClear) as completely transparent.

Comment: When I try this, I get `identifier "DWM_BLURBEHIND" is undefined`. Is there a library I need to include?

Comment: @pholz You can get rid of that last pixel by setting the region outside the client area : `CreateRectRgn(-1, -1, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 29):

This is an old question, but since newer versions of Windows have compositing and support, as datenwolf hints, for opengl, we can use some of that special sauce for accomplishing this. Although it is also trivial with DirectX (go figure...) Microsoft did add compositing hints to opengl contexts. Yay anti-trust fears!

So instead of an inefficient copy-to-physical-memory action, we can have the compositing engine just understand how to make use of the opengl context.

So, you have to create an opengl context with a pixelformat that specifies an alpha channel and that it should use composition (line 82). Then, you use the DwmApi.h routines to enable a blurred window (line 179) with a completely invalid region specified, which will blur nothing and leave the window transparent. (You need to specify a black+transparent brush on the window class! Oddly!) Then, you actually just use opengl as you are used to using it. In the event loop, every chance you get, you can just draw and swap buffers (line 201) and remember to enable GL_BLEND! :)

Please review/fork https://gist.github.com/3644466 or just view the following code snippet based off of the OP's own answer with this technique instead (you can just plop this in an empty project):

```cpp
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#include <dwmapi.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")

#pragma comment (lib, "dwmapi.lib")

#include <assert.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#ifdef  assert
#define verify(expr) if(!expr) assert(0)
#else verify(expr) expr
#endif

const TCHAR szAppName[]=_T("TransparentGL");
const TCHAR wcWndName[]=_T("TransparentGL");

HDC hDC;            
HGLRC m_hrc;        
int w = 240;
int h = 240;

BOOL initSC() {
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);        
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);        
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);          
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);            

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);             
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}

void resizeSC(int width,int height) {
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
}

BOOL renderSC() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                              // Drawing Using Triangles
        glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                      // Set The Color To Red
        glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top
        glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);                      // Set The Color To Green
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
        glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);                      // Set The Color To Blue
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    return 0;
}

BOOL CreateHGLRC(HWND hWnd) {
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
      sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
      1,                                // Version Number
      PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW      |         // Format Must Support Window
      PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL      |         // Format Must Support OpenGL
      PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION |         // Format Must Support Composition
      PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                 // Must Support Double Buffering
      PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                    // Request An RGBA Format
      32,                               // Select Our Color Depth
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                 // Color Bits Ignored
      8,                                // An Alpha Buffer
      0,                                // Shift Bit Ignored
      0,                                // No Accumulation Buffer
      0, 0, 0, 0,                       // Accumulation Bits Ignored
      24,                               // 16Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)
      8,                                // Some Stencil Buffer
      0,                                // No Auxiliary Buffer
      PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                   // Main Drawing Layer
      0,                                // Reserved
      0, 0, 0                           // Layer Masks Ignored
   };     

   HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
   int PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
   if (PixelFormat == 0) {
      assert(0);
      return FALSE ;
   }

   BOOL bResult = SetPixelFormat(hdc, PixelFormat, &pfd);
   if (bResult==FALSE) {
      assert(0);
      return FALSE ;
   }

   m_hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
   if (!m_hrc){
      assert(0);
      return FALSE;
   }

   ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            if(m_hrc) {
                wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
                wglDeleteContext(m_hrc) ;
            }
            PostQuitMessage(0) ;
        break;

        default: 
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR str,int nWinMode) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WindowFunc;
    wc.cbClsExtra  = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra  = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hThisInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(0x00000000);
    wc.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("RegisterClassEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, szAppName, wcWndName,
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 200, 150, w, h,
                    NULL, NULL, hThisInst, NULL);

    if(!hWnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("CreateWindowEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    DWM_BLURBEHIND bb = {0};
    HRGN hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, -1, -1);
    bb.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
    bb.hRgnBlur = hRgn;
    bb.fEnable = TRUE;
    DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd, &bb);

    CreateHGLRC(hWnd);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, m_hrc);
    initSC();
    resizeSC(w, h);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

    MSG msg;  
    while(1) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else {
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            wglMakeCurrent(hdc, m_hrc);

            renderSC();

            SwapBuffers(hdc);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        }
    } 

    return (FALSE); 
}
```

Comment: Works great on Win 7. When I made the window size exactly equal to the screen size the background became black instead of transparent (as if Aero assumes the window is fullscreen, even though it isn't actually). I was able to work around this by making the window 1 pixel taller than the screen, i.e. use `window_x = 0, window_y = -1, window_width = screen_width, window_height = screen_height + 1` as the values passed to CreateWindowEx, then call `glViewport(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height)` as usual.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Just exactly what I needed. All other answers show the approach of drawing to an offscreen buffer and then BitBlt() it to a visible drawing context which is super slow and doesn't work for any serious application.

Answer (score 10):

This would be very easy if OpenGL windows were allowed to be layered. But they are not, so you'll have to go for something else.

What you could do is to create a layered window (WS_EX_LAYERED + SetLayeredWindowAttributes() - Google 'em if you don't know them) to handle the transparency, and a hidden OpenGL window for the rendering. Render the OpenGL scene to an off-screen buffer, read it back and share it with the layered window, then bitblt (GDI function) it to the layered window.

This might be too slow for very complex stuff, but will give you the effect you are asking for, and work on Windows 2000 and above.

EDIT: When it comes to creating the actual off-screen buffer, framebuffer objects (FBOs) are probably your best bet. You could just draw on the hidden OpenGL window, though I think I recall someone posting about running into troubles with that, because of pixel ownership - FBOs are recommended. You could also use pixel buffers (pbuffers), but these are kind of outdated (stamped "legacy"), and FBOs are considered the modern way to do this. FBOs should give you hardware acceleration (if supported), and won't itself limit you to a specific OpenGL version. You'll need an OpenGL context to use it, so you'll have to create that hidden OpenGL window and set up the FBO from there.

Here are some resources on FBOs: 
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) 
[FBO](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) 
[Gamedev article](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2331.asp) 
[Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_offscreen/opengl_offscreen.html) (for mac, but might be helpful)

Comment: This is similar to what I'd suggest.  Render your OpenGL scene to memory (FBO or similar) and then use glReadPixels to store into a bitmap object.  Then you can pick your transparent color and bitblt it to the screen using GDI.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I was trying to port the Xlib solution to Gtk+. After a lot of study I finally made it so I really want to share it here for anyone in need.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkscreen.h>
#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>
#include <gtk/gtkgl.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

static gboolean supports_alpha = FALSE;

/***
 *** Configure the OpenGL framebuffer.
***/
static GdkGLConfig* configure_gl(void)
{
    GdkGLConfig* glconfig;

    /* Try double-buffered visual */
    glconfig = gdk_gl_config_new_by_mode(GDK_GL_MODE_RGBA |
        GDK_GL_MODE_ALPHA |
        GDK_GL_MODE_DEPTH |
        GDK_GL_MODE_DOUBLE);
    if (glconfig == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot find the double-buffered visual.\n");
        printf("No appropriate OpenGL-capable visual found.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Find GLConfig with alpha channel.\n");
    return glconfig;
}

static void screen_changed(GtkWidget* widget, GdkScreen* old_screen, gpointer userdata)
{
    /* To check if the display supports alpha channels, get the colormap */
    GdkScreen* screen = gtk_widget_get_screen(widget);
    GdkColormap* colormap = gdk_screen_get_rgba_colormap(screen);

    if (!colormap)
    {
        printf("Your screen does not support alpha channels!\n");
        colormap = gdk_screen_get_rgb_colormap(screen);
        supports_alpha = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Your screen supports alpha channels!\n");
        supports_alpha = TRUE;
    }

    gtk_widget_set_colormap(widget, colormap);
}

static gboolean expose(GtkWidget* widget, GdkEventExpose* event, gpointer userdata)
{
    GdkGLContext* glcontext = gtk_widget_get_gl_context(widget);
    GdkGLDrawable* gldrawable = gtk_widget_get_gl_drawable(widget);

    if (!gdk_gl_drawable_gl_begin(gldrawable, glcontext))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
    glVertex3f(+0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
    glVertex3f(+0.5f, +0.5f, 0);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, +0.5f, 0);
    glEnd();

    gdk_gl_drawable_swap_buffers(gldrawable);

    gdk_gl_drawable_gl_end(gldrawable);
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    /* Added to config GLConfig */
    GdkGLConfig* glconfig = configure_gl();
    gtk_widget_set_gl_capability(window,
        glconfig,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        GDK_GL_RGBA_TYPE);

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 400);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Alpha Demo");
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete-event", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

    gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(window, TRUE);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(expose), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "screen-changed", G_CALLBACK(screen_changed), NULL);

    screen_changed(window, NULL, NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `` gcc main.c -o main `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 gtkglext-1.0` ``. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 (in addition to gtk, you'll need to install `libgtkglext1-dev`).

**EDIT**

I changed the rendering code from simply a `glClear` to a rectangle.

The code is a modified version from [this question](https://community.khronos.org/t/gtkglext/25597) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/).

[image]

Comment: Interesting, one of the links you shared is also from another answer of mine. Make sure to up vote everything. If you share a screenshot of this program running so we know what it looks like, I will up vote this answer.

Comment: Oh sorry because although I use stackoverflow a lot (from google), I lost my password and haven't logged in for long. I will do so in the future. Thanks for the other answer also.

Comment: And thanks for the advice. I will try to add a screenshot to improve but it's still your own choice whether to up vote it or not. @karlphillip

Comment: That screenshot will add a lot of value to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can render the 3d scene to a pbuffer and blit it to screen using a color key.

Answer (score 0):

The ClanLib game SDK does this.

If you only require a static transparent border use the following technique:

Creates 5 windows

AAAAA

B###C

B###C

DDDDD

A,B,C,D are layered windows

"#" is the main window.

See the images at the bottom of - http://clanlib.org/wiki/ClanLib_2.2.9_Release_Notes

Comment: Thanks, but the question specifically asks how to do this effect using Win32 API **only**.