# How to create OpenGL-enabled window with transparent background using xlib and glx

Tags: opengl, background, transparent, xlib, glx

I'd like to create a window with transparent background and then render something onto it using OpenGL. I don't want to use the trick where whatever is behind the window is captured and then painted as a background - I want real transparency (I have composition manager running). I'm not using any GUI library (GTK, QT, ...), just raw xlib and glx.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but one dude shows how to achieve this in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9215724/176769), without using SDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [these patches to Neverball and SDL](http://nullkey.ath.cx/stuff/misc/neverball-argb/).  They seem to be based on [NVidia's driver documentation](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/256.53/README/xcompositeextension.html).

I haven't tried it, but it looks as if you just select the correct GLX config (`GLX_RGBA_BIT`), clear your window appropriately, and have a compositor running, it should Just Work™.