# Animate 3D object on windows desktop

Tags: wpf, opengl, animation, 3d, directx

I need to draw and animate a 3D object on windows desktop that the user can interact with (a dog for example). User interaction assumes clicks, display of (iregular shape) dialogs for user input etc.

- Do you know any concrete way to achieve this?

I am thinking I have several options, any recomendations, which one is best, easiest?

- WPF
- OpenGL
- DirectX
- XNA

Are there any libraries (free or paid) that can help?

Comment: See the answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052940/win32-how-to-make-an-opengl-rendering-context-with-transparent-background .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some reasearch and it seems like WPF is a good choice.

- It can import 3D models and animate
  them or sub-parts.
- I can interact with the mouse on
  individual pieces of the model.
- I can apply textures. Play with
  lights and camera etc.
- Also easy to use.

Model is created in 3D modeling tool (3DStudioMax, Maya etc.) and then it's exported to XAML for use in WPF.

Comment: @karl It's ok, I don't target XP. But why doesn't work? I did a simple test app and was able to load a 3D model on XP. Please feel free to add an answer with your explanation. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize, I confused WPF with DWM (yes, Alzheimer at this age, who knew?!). You are absolutely right.