# Animate parts of a single 3D object in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, 3d

Is it possible to animate just a part of a 3D object in WPF? For instance if I have a human object can I make him wave his hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Answer to related question:
[Animate 3D object on windows desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645222/animate-3d-object-on-windows-desktop)