# Transparent window above OpenGL

Tags: wpf, opengl, background, transparency

My application have OpenGL Engine in a WPF hosted Window.
I created half-transparent widget (as Window object) that should display content above OpenGL window. Sometimes when application processing data, widgets backgrounds becomes black (see attached image).
Does anybody know what it is. How can I resolve this problem.[image]

Comment: As far as I know transparency only works between WPF items so I'm surprised it sometimes works for you.

Comment: OpenGL window is not transparent but wpf window is. It is works very well but this problems comes when asyncronous rendering occures i think (my opinion)

Comment: As far as I know WPF windows are only transparent to other WPF windows. You cannot put a WPF transparent control over a Windows Forms control and expect them to work.

Comment: See this: http://khason.net/blog/transparent-wpf-control-over-unmanaged-window-handle/

Comment: There's an [interesting post here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4055059/176769), it might be just what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Since Vista, Windows supports a new [`PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231189(v=prot.10).aspx) flag `PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION`. If this flag is set, new OpenGL contexts created from `HDC`s of windows configured with this flag will integrate into the desktop composition system.

Answer (score 0):

It's not guaranteed to work at all. OpenGL windows are not composited with WPF transparency, either below or above. It may work sometimes, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: Compositing can be enabled for compositing. This is done through a new PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR flag.

Comment: First, that only composites with things behind it, not on top of it. Second, I don't see the equivalent in [wglChoosePixelFormatARB](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_pixel_format.txt), which is where most people get their pixel formats from. Otherwise, you couldn't use sRGB framebuffers or multisampling.

Comment: @datenwolf: And third, there's no guarantee that PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION will not turn off hardware acceleration or force use of the Microsoft GL driver. There's no guarantee it will do that either, but I'd want more info before trying to make such a change.