# glBlendFunc and glClearColor alpha parameter

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

In OpenGL for achieving a proper transparency effect I should use `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` but with that blending function an alpha parameter in `glClearColor` becomes meaningless. When I change an alpha parameter in `glClearColor` I still get the same effect. When can I use the alpha parameter in `glClearColor`? What kind of effects Can I achieve?

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`glClearColor` sets the color (and alpha value) a RGBA framebuffer will be cleared to with `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`. The framebuffer alpha value would be taken into account with `GL_DST_ALPHA` or `GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA` blend functions.

However your regular on-screen window framebuffer usually doesn't carry an alpha value. [Notable exceptions exist of course, for example transparent windows with the background shining through, but they're a bit tedious to set up, and will still receive all mouse events, even if over "transparent" areas.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9215724/524368)

Framebuffers with an alpha channel are mostly of interest als *render to texture* targets.

So in your case, the clear color is of no particular interest for you. You're much more likely interested in the 4th parameter of `glColor4f` or textures with an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is the Alpha, not transparency It means you can not see it at all when it's 0. When it is 1 you can fully see it. You can see it at half power, if it's 0.5f.

Comment: The question was about the alpha parameter in `glClearColor` and implicitly the meaning of a framebuffer's alpha channel I  general. Alpha is a user-defined property which can mean transparency, opacity or something completely different, depending on which blend equations are chosen.