# drawing transparent windows form element like button on top of opengl context

Tags: winforms, opengl

[image]is it possible to overlay a transparent button like  a round button on OpenGL rendering context?when I Transparent a UI element it blend with  original window background not rendered context.

Comment: What middleware/framework are you using, to generate the UI element ? The compositor that is generating the final (full)screen needs to be aware of both the OpenGL context and the UI element to be able to blend both of them.

Comment: I am using .net Windows form o genertae UI elements.

Comment: after research to do this i think its needes to copy frame buffer to Window HDC.lik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052940/how-to-make-an-opengl-rendering-context-with-transparent-background?rq=1